# Formatting a String to Remove Scientific Notation - Java

Tags: java, string, floating-point, bigdecimal

I have the following code which splits a string of numbers (separated by a space) and then creates an array of floats :

```
//Split the string and then build a float array with the values.
String[] tabOfFloatString = value.split(" ");
int length = tabOfFloatString.length;
System.out.println("Length of float string is" + length);
float[] floatsArray = new float[length];
for (int l=0; l<length; l++) {
float res = Float.parseFloat(tabOfFloatString[l]);
    System.out.println("Float is " + res);
    floatsArray[l]=res;
}
```

The problem is that some of the values in the string are formatted with scientific notation - e.g they read -3.04567E-8.

What I want to do is end up with a float which does not contain the E number.

I have been reading this thread which suggests that I could use BigDecimal, however am unable to get this to work - is this the best approach or should I try something else ? [How to convert a string 3.0103E-7 to 0.00000030103 in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229516/how-to-convert-a-string-3-0103e-7-to-0-00000030103-in-java)

Comment: A float doesn't contain the E number. Scientific notation is one of the ways that floats may be represented. If the default format doesn't work for you, take a look into java.text.DecimalFormat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below is your code slightly modified. As per me this works well and doesn't actually cares he order of the exponents:

```
public void function() {
    String value = "123456.0023 -3.04567E-8 -3.01967E-20";
    String[] tabOfFloatString = value.split(" ");
    int length = tabOfFloatString.length;
    System.out.println("Length of float string is" + length);
    float[] floatsArray = new float[length];
    for (int l = 0; l < length; l++) {
        String res = new BigDecimal(tabOfFloatString[l]).toPlainString();
        System.out.println("Float is " + res);
        floatsArray[l] = Float.parseFloat(res);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answered doesn't work for me, When do

```
floatsArray[l] = Float.parseFloat(res);
```

the Float.parseFloat(res) change non scientific anotation into scientific anotation so i had to delete it.

This one worked:

```
public String[] avoidScientificNotation(float[] sensorsValues)
{
     int length = sensorsValues.length;
     String[] valuesFormatted = new String[length];

     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
     {
         String valueFormatted = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(sensorsValues[i])).toPlainString();
         valuesFormatted[i] = valueFormatted;
     }
    return valuesFormatted;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.############################################################");
System.out.println(format.format(Math.ulp(0F)));
System.out.println(format.format(1F));
```

Answer (score 1):

The float doesn't contain an `e`, that is just how it is being displayed to you.  You can use `DecimalFormat` to change how it is displayed.

http://ideone.com/jgN6l

```
java.text.DecimalFormat df = new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,###.######################################################");
System.out.println(df.format(res));
```

You will notice some odd looking numbers though, due to floating point.