# How to remove the E7 when a number is too high?

Tags: java, android, floating-point, notation

I'm working on my application and i need to increase my float by 0.2 on every click but when the float is high i get this problem

This is my float:

```
11162061
```

And the output is :

```
1.1162061E7
```

But i need the value without the E7 and without the dot ,how can i remove it ? What if i multiply the output for 10000000 ?
I tried with BigDecimal but i get 11162061.000002314 ,i need a long number after the dot and only 1 decimal before the dot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520608/formatting-a-string-to-remove-scientific-notation-java 

see if this topic helps you

Comment: @Telmo Ivo This works only if i need more decimals ( like this 2,034144314 ) but i need this: 111162061,2